# Write more than 65535 rows to a csv file in Python?

Tags: python, csv, file

I have the following logic in a Python script:

```
def importAndAnalyze(rowLimit = 3):
    layerProperties = iface.addVectorLayer("Downloads/parcels-shp/parcels.shp", "Parcels", "ogr")
    if not layerProperties:
        print("layerProperties failed to load!")
    layerEntrances = iface.addVectorLayer("Downloads/Metro_Stations-shp/Metro_Stations.shp", "Metro_Stations", "ogr")
    if not layerEntrances:
        print("layerEntrances failed to load!")
    features = layerProperties.getFeatures()
    counter = 0
    featuresSelected = []
    Path('Desktop/output.csv').touch()

    with open('Desktop/output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        csvWriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
        csvWriter.writerow(['Tooltip', 'Lat','Lon', 'Distance'])
        for feature in features:
            if counter < rowLimit:
                csvWriter.writerow([feature['TOOLTIP'], feature.geometry().centroid().asPoint().y(),feature.geometry().centroid().asPoint().x(), Ranker.calculateDistance(feature, layerEntrances)])
                if counter % 100 == 0:
                    csvfile.flush()
            else:
                break
            counter += 1

Ranker.importAndAnalyze(1000000)
```

When I feed it 800,000 rows of information, with the rowLimit variable set to a million, it currently saves exactly 65,535 rows to the output.csv file, then stops saving new rows, even as the script continues to run for hours.

How do I get my script to save the other 734,465 rows?

===

EDIT: There was a lot of rightful speculation in the comments/answers about whether my `rowLimit` variable was actually set to a million. So I added a bit more code to show the context of how this is running.

Comment: If the intent of `rowlimit` is to constrain the size of the file, then your code should `break` out of the `for` loop when it is reached instead of endlessly looping through `features` and doing nothing with what it retrieves.

Comment: The `w` option in your csv file opening context may be the issue. Change it to `a` to append data.

Comment: @BoarGules thanks, that's good advice about breaking out of the loop. I've edited the code sample to adhere to that advice.

Comment: @Nick that's a good guess, but it didn't appear to fix the problem. We're still stuck at 65,535 rows.

Comment: Python doesn't block you from writing as many lines as you want. Are you sure that you have more than 65536 rows? Are you sure that `rowLimit` is `1000000`?  Are you sure that your `counter` starts a `0`? Are you sure that this part of the code is the culprit? Can you prove it?

Comment: There is no restriction in Python that would reject content after 65535 rows. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Another question - are you sure that `features` actually has more than 65,535 features?

Comment: `features` contains more than 65,535 features. We figured out that this was a problem with Apple's Numbers application, which limits viewable rows of a csv to 65,535, even if there are more rows than that.

Answer (score 2):

The `csv` module by itself imposes no such constraint. Your code stops writing when it reaches the variable `rowLimit` (which isn't defined in your question) so the obvious and trivial solution is to take that out.

Here's a stab at a refactoring which also renames your variables to adhere with Python conventions.

```py
with open('Desktop/output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Tooltip', 'Lat','Lon', 'Distance'])
    for counter, feature in enumerate(features):
        # if counter == row_limit:
        #     raise StopIteration('row_limit reached')
        csv_writer.writerow([feature['TOOLTIP'], feature.geometry().centroid().asPoint().y(),feature.geometry().centroid().asPoint().x(), Ranker.calculateDistance(feature, layerEntrances)])
        if counter % 100 == 0:
            csvfile.flush()
```

It's of course possible that you use a program to read the resulting CSV file which can't cope with arbitrarily large files; at least Excel seems to have a problem with sheets larger than 65,535 rows (but friends don't let friends use Excel).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A google search seems to suggest this number of rows is relevant. https://www.google.com/search?q=65535+rows+csv&oq=65535+rows+csv

Comment: A trivial exercise with your local Python should reveal that it easily writes a million lines without issues. Your Google search seems to return results for Java predominantly. Probably Excel has a problem with large files too, but who wants to use Excel?

Comment: Aha! I'm using Apple Numbers to open this file. I think Excel fixed the sheet size problem a decade ago, but maybe Apple Numbers still hasn't. I'll take a look at the file in Vim ...

Comment: Then which OS are you on? I can't repro on macOS or Linux.

Comment: MacOS. I looked in Vim, and sure enough, more rows show up. So it's an Apple Numbers problem. If you edit this answer to include that information, I'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('Desktop/output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    csvWriter.writerow(['Tooltip', 'Lat','Lon', 'Distance'])
    counter = 0
    for feature in features[:rowLimit]:
        csvWriter.writerow([feature['TOOLTIP'], feature.geometry().centroid().asPoint().y(),feature.geometry().centroid().asPoint().x(), Ranker.calculateDistance(feature, layerEntrances)])
        if counter % 100 == 0:
            csvfile.flush()
        counter += 1
    csvfile.flush()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Apologies for being dense: What did you change?

Comment: you need to have one flush() at the end of the loop to handle the last batch.

Comment: The last flush should not actually be necessary, as closing the file (which happens when you exit the context manager block) will flush it anyway.